# Python profiling: using line_profiler's @profile decorator results in error

Tags: python, profiling

I'm trying to profile some Python code using the `line_profiler` module, but I can't get it to work. I'm on Windows 7 and using Python 2.7.6.

When running `kernprof -l -v test.py` on the following `test.py` file:

```
@profile
def test():
    a = 1
    b = 1
    return a + b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print test()
```

I get:

```
C:\>kernprof -l -v C:\test.py
Wrote profile results to test.py.lprof
Timer unit: 3.01262e-07 s

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\path_to_kernprof\kernprof-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\path_to_kernprof\kernprof.py", line 221, in main
    execfile(script_file, ns, ns)
  File "C:\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    @profile
NameError: name 'profile' is not defined
```

Obviously, the code will run fine if I comment out the line containing `line_profiler`'s @profile decorator. What am I doing wrong, here?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error.

Comment: I assume it's some sort of installation issue.

Comment: As a side note, I've switched to the `pprofile` module for my profiling needs, which works just fine.

Comment: I get the same error, and `pprofile` works for me too. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Might be related to python 2 and futures, see [this](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler/issues/12) bug report, [this](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler/pull/25) pull request fixes this issue. Before a new version is uploaded to pypi, you can modify the code accordingly to that [commit](https://github.com/Nodd/line_profiler/commit/74b83c7d15c762cbed7ebdf3794f6b07013a57bc).

Answer (score 2):

```
from memory_profiler import profile

@profile

def my_func():
    a = [1] * (10 ** 6)
    b = [2] * (2 * 10 ** 7)
    del b
    return a
```

or:

```
python -m memory_profiler example.py
```

https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/

Answer (score -1):

That's result of a bug in `networkx` package 1.11. Downgrade like so:

```
pip uninstall networkx
pip install networkx==1.7
```

Comment: I had the same issue. Unfortunatelly Networkx downgrade didn't solve it.